# Finding zeros of $f(z)=2z^6-5z^2+e^{-3}\sin(z)$ in $A=\{z:1<|z|<3\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How many zeros, counting multiplicity, does the function 
$$f(z)=2z^6-5z^2+e^{-3}\sin(z)$$ have in the annulus $A=\{z:1<|z|<3\}$?

I'm trying to use Rouche's theorem. First for $|z|=3$, $|2z^6|>|-5z^2+e^{-3}\sin{z}|$ so we have $6$ zeros.

While on $|z|=1$, $|2z^6-5z^2|\ge |5z^2|-2|z^6|=3>|e^{-3}\sin z|.$ So we get $2$ zeros inside the circle. So my guess is we should have $4$ zeros in the annulus, but how can I confirm that no zeros exist on the circle? Is this the right way to approach this problem? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Haven't you just shown that on each boundary circle one term *strictly* dominates the other one in absolute value? How can there be a zero on the boundary after that?

Comment: @fedja Oh yes you're right. So is this the right method to count the zeros?

Comment: Yes, it is. You are doing everything perfectly right and your only problem here is insufficient self-confidence :-)